# Filtering differents date columns by two or more dates in data studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a list of objects. In my case, the object is a contract (agreement). The contract has two dates: the beginning and the end of the contract. Both dates are different columns.

I want to make it possible to filter all contracts by start and end date. for example, all contracts where the contract start data is 01.03.2020 - 31.03.2020 and end date is 01.11.2020 - 30.11.2020.

If I use the date range control, then it looks only the date range demension, which can be only one field (for example, only the beginning of the contract). But i need a solution where i can filter by one date or/and another date.

please help me how I could solve this problem.

Data structure:

[image]

Table settings:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way that it can be achieved is by creating two [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) and adding them to two Advanced Filter [Controls](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144), where the values will be filtered in the `YYYYMMDD` format e.g. `27 Nov 2020` would be `20201127` (adapt the format as required by changing the inputs in the [`FORMAT_DATETIME`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9730334) function):

## 1) Start Date

### 1.1) Calculated Field

```
CAST(FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y%m%d", start_date) AS NUMBER )
```

### 1.2) Control

- ***Type***: Advanced Filter
- ***Control Field***: `Start Date`
- ***Search Type***: `>=`

## 2) End Date

### 2.1) Calculated Field

```
CAST(FORMAT_DATETIME("%Y%m%d", end_date) AS NUMBER )
```

### 2.2) Control

- ***Type***: Advanced Filter
- ***Control Field***: `End Date`
- ***Search Type***: `<=`

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b605c4c3-4b04-4708-82cd-0ed0f2ecab3a) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]